# How to change .MOV file format to .AVI in Canon 650D

Tags: file-format, canon-650d, hd-video

I have Canon 650D which I use mostly for video shoots. My question is:

How can I change the video format via the camera settings? Is there any possibility to do that? The reason because my video editor doesn't support `.MOV` files for which I have to convert it into different formats like `WMV`. Note that I don't want to compromise the quality of video.

Comment: As far as Google can tell, Mov is the only file format. You can choose between H.264/MPEG-4 encoding modes though.

Comment: For better or for worse, questions about video are off-topic here on Photography SE - this would possibly be on-topic at [Audio-Video Production](http://avp.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Moeed: You really need to ask video related questions over at [AVP](http://avp.stackexchange.com). These types of questions are, and always will be, off topic here, as there is a site dedicated to audio and video, full of people who are more likely to have the answers than we do here at PHOTO.stackexchange.com. That said, you appear to be cross-posting the same question to both sites. Given your history here, I am curious why you continue to do that. It is clear your questions are not on topic here, and cannot be adequately answered here, and are certainly not welcomed by our membership.

Answer (score 3):

#### The 650D shoots video in MOV format only

But don't worry about quality... WMV, AVI and MOV are just container formats and their construction has limited bearing on the encoded contents inside (TIFF also is the same.)  That means converting to your preferred container can be done quickly and with no loss of quality.  It's just an extra step is all.

For any follow-up questions on how best to do the conversion [Audio-Video Production.SE](https://video.stackexchange.com/) would be the place to ask (or has probably been asked already.)